# Python variable returns "generator object"

Tags: python

I am writing some test code, but the submissions variable is returning `<generator object get_content at 0x009D9930>`.

The variable should be returning a list  of submissions, similar to this

```
['10 :: Gun.io Debuts Group Funding for Open Source Projects\n Gun.io',
 '24 :: Support the Free Software Foundation',
 '67 :: The 10 Most Important Open Source Projects of 2011',
 '85 :: Plan 9 - A distributed OS with a unified communicatioprotocol  I/O...',
  '2 :: Open-source webOS is dead on arrival ']
```

This is the code, the library is on pip as praw.

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='/u/Ugion test code')
submissions = r.get_subreddit('opensource').get_hot(limit=5)
[str(x) for x in submissions]
```

Comment: Yes, so? So `submissions` is a generator object.

Comment: you should add the minimal amount of context to make your question understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comprehensions don't modify an object in place; they create a new one. You have to save a reference.

```
submissions = [str(x) for x in submissions]
```

Comment: Thanks! The test code came from the project site, so i assumed it would work out of the box